# prevent ESB from sequence returning cached values

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a sequence that performs an insert in the database and responds with the unique ID of the inserted row. However I have noticed that when this proxy receives many requests, Some responses sent back in the payload have duplicated values.

This is part of my sequence code

```
<dblookup>
   <connection>
      <pool>
         <dsName>DSNAME</dsName>
      </pool>
   </connection>
   <statement>
      <sql>select SEQUENCE1.nextval as uniqueId from dual</sql>
            <result name="uniqueId" column="uniqueId"/>
   </statement>
</dblookup>
<dbreport>
   <connection>
   <pool>
      <dsName>DSNAME</dsName>
   </pool>
   </connection>
   <statement>
      <sql>Insert Into RECORDS_TABLE (ID_ROW, DATA) Values(?,?)</sql>
   <parameter expression="get-property('uniqueId')" type="NUMERIC"/>
   <parameter expression="//sentData" type="VARCHAR"/>
   </statement>
</dbreport>
   <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
   <format>
      <hh:myResponse xmlns:hh="http://samplens.com/sample/">
      <hh:uniqueId>$1</hh:uniqueId>
      </hh:myResponse>
   </format>
<args>
 <arg xmlns:hh="http://samplens.com/sample/" evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uniqueId')"/>  </args>

</payloadFactory>
```

This works okay for a small number of requests, but for large number of requests, ESB returns responses of old `uniqueId`, Is there any different approach to prevent this or does anyone know the best way to resolve this issue. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: please check if the [response caching](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Response+Caching) is disabled, otherwise there's no reason ESB would return the same value. (I've seen some proxies caching the GET responses as well)

Comment: Thanks @gusto2 Unfortunately, It is disabled.